# setTimeout Performance Effects in Angular

Tags: performance, angular, settimeout

I haven't found good information on `setTimeout` usage and Angular 2+ performance. How do `setTimeout`s affect performance, and what does Angular do when a `setTimeout` is triggered? One site suggested it causes a dirty check, but in my tests, I'm not seeing a notable difference.

UI USAGE EXAMPLE: While I try to avoid setTimeouts wherever possible, I run into the need on UI components with relative frequency.  For example, assuming all possible components are loaded on the webapp, after a user interaction, I may want to get the offsetWidth of an element, but it won't return the actual width until the element is rendered.  That's the simplest example of many other UI related code where a timeless setTimeout is perfect. So when I set the property `elemWidth` (continuing the example), I'd expect/hope Angular would only care that I changed one property in one component instance and not do any other object checking.  When I removed all setTimeouts from my entire UI component library to test performance against a webapp using many instances of all of them, Chrome doesn't show any benefit from removing those...I want the fastest components possible, so how do setTimeouts affect Angular 2+ performance, and what's Angular's reaction to them?

Answer (score 0):

Angular just runs Javascript, so I don't think `setTimeout` in Angular would be any better or worse than your vanilla Javascript.

> I may want to get the offsetWidth of an element, but it won't return the actual width until the element is rendered

Use the [`ngAfterViewInit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) lifecycle hook. It's a function Angular calls when the view has been rendered. At that point you will know what your UI looks like.

Using a lot of setTimeouts sounds like a hack to be fair. Look into what events the objects you're observing trigger and bind to those.

Comment: What I'm hoping to avoid is Angular needing to unnecessarily check for additional changes like a digest cycle in AngularJS, and only be concerned with the change.

Comment: Lifecycle hooks are great for when the component is setting up, or being taken down, but in these UI interaction-triggered events, some of these dynamic renderings happen after the component is fully setup.